# Using a seperate date for FTD outside of datamodel in excel report

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot

I have a data model named **`Sanction`** in the following format.

```
Sl. Date        Loc     Product   Num   Amount
1   01-06-2023  Loc1    Pro1      2     5
2   02-06-2023  Loc2    Pro2      5     6
```

I am currently using the following measures

```
FTD:=TODAY()
FTD_AMT:=CALCULATE(SUM('Sanction'[Amount]),FILTER('Sanction','Sanction'[Date]='Sanction'[FTD]))
MTD_AMT:=CALCULATE(SUM('Sanction'[Amount]),DATESMTD('Sanction'[Date]))
FTD_NUM:=CALCULATE(SUM('Sanction'[No]),FILTER('Sanction','Sanction'[Date]='Sanction'[FTD] ))
MTD_NUM:=CALCULATE(SUM('Sanction'[No]),DATESMTD('Sanction'[Date]))
```

Now, the workbook is working fine except for two problems.

1. The FTD is a fixed value i.e. **`today()`** and I want it to be a variable date that I can choose or pick from the workbook.
2. The MTD function is not working properly as it's showing data from other months too. I need it to show data from the month of FTD. i.e. If FTD is 05-July-2023, MTD function should display data of Month July 2023 only.